# connecting to remote broker and consumer result with no messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have the following flow:
1- producer running in a linux computer that supposed to write messages to a remote broker
2- remote broker and consumer (both of them in a windows 10 machine)

my problem is whenever I run the producer my consumer doesn't get any messages. the producer is connected to the broker but no messages is being received by the consumer however when I tested them (producer, consumer and broker) both in the same machine they worked fine.

All of the components are running in the same network, and the firewall is deactivated in the windows machine.

Producer.py

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='windowIP:9092')
producer.send('testSite', b'Hello, World!')
```

consumer

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server windowIP:9092 --topic testSite --from-beginning
```

server.config

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://windowsIP:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://windowsIP:9092
zookeeper.connect= windowsIP:2181
```

consumer.config

```
bootstrap.servers=windowsIP:9092,windowsIP:9093
```

Comment: Can you please post log generating from consumer application

Comment: I run the consumer in the terminal how can i activate the logs? @gatisahu

Comment: config/log4j.properties can change to log

Comment: i checked the logs, it is empty. to test if the producer is connected to the broker: i tried to send the data to unknown topic from the producer and it was created inside the broker.